# How do I assign a color to a specific part of a 3d Model, rather than the whole thing?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, objects, color

To summarize, I am an absolute beginner in Blender, and I chose to download a pair of glasses as a 3D Model (from: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/glasses-4b8a1e54f3084c63828fe8c324198aec), as can be seen in the image below.
[image: The Glasses:]

However, what I wanted to for its aesthetics, was to color the Lens Frames white, while coloring the Temples black (They're both the color "#29282C" as of now), but whenever I tried changing the colors of either of them using the "Material Properties" tab, the entire model would change in color, rather than simply the part that I chose.

Could you please provide me with possible solutions to this dilemma?

Comment: If temples and frame are different objects that share the same material then you will find a number right next to the material's name, presumably 2 or 3 depending on how many objects use this. If you click on the number, it will create a duplicate of the material which you can now change while the other stays the same. I guess the best will be to do that on the frame since it's one I suppose, and the temples are two? So keep the material on the temples and change the frame. But this is just scratching on the surface of shading and texturing objects, I would strongly recommend doing tutorials.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Gordon. I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Select the object, go into Edit Mode, and enter 'face select.' Then select one of the faces that you want to have a separate color for, then go to 'Select,' 'Select Similar,' then 'Material.' Then Go to the Material Properties panel, create a new material, and click 'Assign' to assign that material to the selected faces. Do this again for the lenses. When this is done, you should have 2 separate materials for the different parts of the mesh that are completely independent of each other.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!!! I am forever in your debt...

Comment: No problemo! :D

Comment: @RESHABAAROSHREDDY The description in your question made it seem like the parts you wanted to assign different materials to were already separate objects... so no need to go into _Edit Mode_ and select faces...?

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry if I didn't explain that properly Mr. Gordon. Yeah, the parts of the glasses weren't considered as separate models, hence why I needed help coloring them individually. It's fine now though, as I figured out how to do it.

Comment: @RESHABAAROSHREDDY -- be sure to click on the "Accept Answer" button so that BlenderMaster15 get credit: points towards his reputation to be helpful to others!